# Slack Modal views: expand the stack to more than 3 before final submission

Tags: user-interface, slack, slack-api, mulesoft

I'm working on a slack bot that have more than 3 modals until I submit it to process.. According to slack docs, the view stack is limit to 3 so I though that I cloud just close the oldest one and free a slot for a new one.. not sure if that make sense (Im actually trying to limit the whole experience to those 3 modals)... in this case goes like this:

1. Slash command --> views.open (open modal step1 to user and send a null response).
2. The user submit step1 modal and I trigger a **push response operation** with the next modal (step2).
3. idem ... showing modal step3 with a review of the values (I store them using Object Store -Mulesoft)..
4. this submit with do some process on the data from the step1 and step2 modals and response with a IM to the user with the result

On the 2nd step I tried to trigger a POST to **views.push** but the trigger ID from the submission is not valid, have to be the trigger id from a block action according to slack.

On step 1 and 2 modals I replace the word SUBMIT with NEXT and only on the final one it say SUBMIT.

One thing... I know that by not closing the views I can close and sort of "go back".. which I will loose if I expand the stack..

I tried to trigger another POST on views.open with a null response for while the response from that POST is good (ok: true)... on the UI... I get the error "*We had some trouble connecting. Try again?*" on the "step1" modal..

Anyone have any ideas on how can I close modal from the bottom of the view stack so I can add a new one and so on? I know the use case may not be the best (slack apps should make thins easier not form after form..) but just want to know if it can be done).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well... I have come a long way since I posted this... I ended up using JS but one thing that I want to share if you are on the same situation is that as long you responde the SUBMIT with an sync acknowledgment (is easier in js) the modal will close and then you can send/open another one and so on...